# NetBeans "Shift Left" analog on PHPStorm

Tags: netbeans, phpstorm

I am deciding to migrate from NetBeans to PHPStorm IDE, and the only feature I have not found in PHPStorm is "Shift Left (Right), Move Down (Up)", which moves a line on one tab to the left, right, or swaps with next or previous line. Does PHPStorm have any analog of this?

Using <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not suitable.

Answer (score 17):

There's no built-in way to Tab/Untab (Indent/Unindent) line w/o making a selection in Jetbrains PhpStorm. So, Tab & Shif+Tab is your only choice.

As for move line Up & Down Try Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down. However this action also interacts with program structure and not just moves line as in text.

Comment: As a vim user, i find that part of the problem is it's always in "insert" mode. In vim while in normal mode you can press ">>" to indent a line by one level. PHPStorm cannot have the double usage of the keys because its always looking to insert new characters.  Thats part of why I consider vim superior, it forces you to spend less time "inserting" and more time thinking about exactly what it is you want to do.

Answer (score 13):

Select your code and then press Shift+TAB to shift to left or just press TAB to shift to right.

Works in phpstorm and wbestorm.

Answer (score 1):

[CTRL] [ALT] [I] will auto indent the line where your cursor is or any selected lines.